# Change the default browser behaviour of interpreting script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

We all know what `<script src="/something.js"></script>` does. That file is loaded in the page and the script is run.

Is there any way to override the default behaviour of interpreting `<script>` elements?

I want the same syntax (`<script src='...'></script>`) that will only get the code from `something.js` (probably via XHR/jQuery ajax) and pass it to a `foo (...) {...}` function. Then I will care what I will do with it.

To clarify the problem:

I can easily create a pseudo `<script>` tag alternative using:

```
<div data-script-src="/1.js"></div>
<div data-script-src="/2.js"></div>
<div data-script-src="/3.js"></div>
<div data-script-src="/4.js"></div>
```

And then in the js side I would do:

```
var $scripts = $("[data-script-src]")
  , scriptContents = [];
(function loadInOrder (i) {
    if (!$scripts[i]) { alert("Loaded"); }
    $.ajax($($scripts[i]).attr("data-script-src"), function (data) {
        scriptContents[i] = data;
        loadInOrder(++i); 
    });
})(0);
```

But how can I replace `div[data-script]` with `<script>`? How can I force the browser **NOT** to load the `<script>` tags that have the attribute `data-load="false"`, for example?

Comment: Could you use the jQuery getScript method to achieve the same results?
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: I think You are using it to analyse... Let's say other sites :). Maybe some deep browser settings? Or downloading site using for example wget, and substitute <script> with something else, and then run Your function? Please submit a little more info ;).

Comment: @Askanison4 I know how to use `$.getScript` but it doesn't change the `<script>` functionality. I want to change the browser to interpret `<script>` tag in a different mode: only get the file content and pass it to a function.

Comment: This is impossible to do with just a `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet here is to use [onbeforescriptexecute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.onbeforescriptexecute).  This event fires right *before* the script executes, so you can then modify the `type` attribute to something other than `text/javascript` (thus telling the browser not to execute the contents).  This will still *load* the data from the server.

Unfortunately, `onbeforescriptexecute` is only supported in FF/Opera.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("beforescriptexecute", function (e) {
                console.log(e.target.innerHTML || e.target.src);
            }, true);
        </script>
        <script>
            console.log("12");
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       Hi 
    </body>
</html>
```

The console output will be:

```
'console.log("12")'
'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'
```

Answer (score 2):

Create Your own PHP file, which will work as a kind of a gate. Then

```
<?php
    $file = file_get_contents(your_url);
    $file = str_replace('<script', '<myscript', $file);
    $file = str_replace('</script>', '</myscript>', $file);
    echo $file;
?>
```

And then if needed add Your type of **real** script that will search for **myscript** tags and run Javascript code...

You can use div element as well (if scripts are loaded in body, and You need validation):

```
substitute: '<script' -> '<div data-id="my-script" '
substitute: '<script' -> '</div>'
```

PS. I don't know if these are Your sites or sites from internet, that You want the default behaviour to be overwritten. So always be careful of what You are "file_getting_contents" because, this will be echoed directly to Your browser.